# "answer suggested by author" status for questions

Tags: discussion

I have asked several questions that went unanswered for so long, I eventually discovered the answer through trial and error.  I don't really want to answer my own question because doing so does not seem to be correct.  I want to encourage someone to answer it (and gain the credit for the answer.)  However, I don't think it would be wrong to explain my answer in the comments, then advertise the fact that I had posted a verified method in my comments.  I'm hoping that doing this would encourage someone with similar experience to write an answer, supported by my comment, and allow me to get some closure.

Comment: Actually, someone else getting credit for work you did would be *the* wrong course of action. You did it, you write it, you collect reputation for the job well done - perfectly fair. If for some reason you don't want the reputation (for example, your friend without an account did it and you are only posting it), then you can use Community Wiki for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your own questions is [perfectably acceptable](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).  There is some additional guidance on a [good question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).  Just make sure your answer will benefit others reading it.